# Boto3 missing several apigateway usage plans

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, boto3

I am getting a list of all of my usage plans in AWS through `Boto3` and noticed that I am missing several usage plans compared to what should be there.  Specifically `Boto3` thinks there are 25 plans while `awscli` counts 39 (which is the number displayed in the AWS console).  Below is the code that I'm using to get the usage plans for my specific setup:

**Python file:**

```
import boto3

session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='myprofile')
plans = session.client('apigateway').get_usage_plans()
print(len(plans.get('items')))
```

Running the file returns the following:

```
$ python3 getplans.py
25
```

While going through `awscli` returns the following:

```
$ aws apigateway get-usage-plans --profile myprofile | jq '.items | length'
39
```

I looked through the output of both and there's just some complete plans that are missing without any real rhyme or reason behind them.  Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out for anyone who finds this question later.  Looks like `Boto3` was paginating the response.  I ended up fixing the problem by using the following code:

```
import boto3

session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='myprofile')
client = session.client('apigateway')
paginator = client.get_paginator('get_usage_plans')
page_iterator = paginator.paginate()
plans = []
for page in page_iterator:
    for plan in page['items']:
        plans.append(plan)
```